# Spring using Jakarta Tiles

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to use Tiles in my application. 
I have a template jsp file which includes the tags

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
```

However the tiles tag URI cannot be resolved.

I have included Struts 1.3.8 Library in my libs directory. This includes struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar.

I have searched forms and tried adding the following to my web.xml file.

```
 <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles-1.1</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

However I have had still no joy.

How can I get the tags to resolve ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok 1, upgrade to Tiles 2.2.2 ... the version of tiles you're attempting to work with is WAY out dated

Second, if possible use spring 3.0.

Spring 2.5.6 has some bugs with the tiles handling that were resolved in 3.0

What are you developing under?

Comment: I am Developing in Netbeans 6.9. I am using Spring 3.0 and I am using the default Strut libraries that are bundled with netbeans 6.9.

Comment: Ok ... as far as using struts you may not have to do that anymore.  SpringMVC does most of the work that struts did and in some cases may do it better. I would suggest looking at the documentation there as well as the provided support by spring with regard to Tiles 2.